# Adding a numbered prefix to column names in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns, prefix

I have 50 dataframes that all have the same column names (e.g. df1: colnames = Id, A,B,C,D, df2: colnames = ID, A,B,C,D and so on).

I need to rename these so it becomes df1: colnames = ID, Mth1_A, Mth1_B, Mth1_C, Mth1_D and then df2: ID, Mth2_A, Mth2_B, Mth2_C, Mth2_D. So each column name should correspond to the number of the dataframe.

I've created a function that does this;

```
col_prefix <- function(df, Mth){
  colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)] <- paste("Mth", colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)], sep = "_")
  return(df)
}
```

But I'm now trying to create a loop to do it for all 50 and I can't get it to work. This is what I've got so far

```
dfList <- c("df1", "df2",...,"df50")

for (filename in dfList){
  i <- get(filename)
  i <- col_prefix(i, Mth)
}
```

Its adding the prefix "Mth" to the datafarmes but its not doing "Mth1", "Mth2", etc. I'm fairly sure this is because in my function Mth is a character but I don't know how to loop through this.

Please help!

Comment: First off, don’t use `get` (nor `assign`) in your code. Instead of having separate data.frames, have a list of data.frames (or one large data.frame). Then the replacement becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a list and use their name (df**1**, df**2**, etc...)to catch the prefix, i.e.

```
l1 <- mget(grep(pattern = "df[0-9]+", x = ls(), value = TRUE))
Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, paste0('MTH', gsub('\\D+', '', y), '_', names(x))), 
    l1, names(l1))

$df1
  MTH1_v1 MTH1_v2
1       5       9
2       6      10
3       7      11

$df2
  MTH2_v1 MTH2_v2
1      15      19
2      16     110
3      17     111
```

To change all names except the first one then,

```
Map(function(x, y) data.frame(x[1], setNames(x[-1], paste0('MTH', gsub('\\D+', '', y), '_', names(x)[-1]))), l1, names(l1))

$df1
  v1 MTH1_v2
1  5       9
2  6      10
3  7      11

$df2
  v1 MTH2_v2
1 15      19
2 16     110
3 17     111
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(v1 = c(5, 6, 7), v2 = c(9, 10, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
dput(df2)
structure(list(v1 = c(15, 16, 17), v2 = c(19, 110, 111)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks I've got that to work but I need the first column to not change as its an ID that I need to keep as is. So I need for df1 colnames: ID, MTH1_v1, MTH1_v2 etc and then df2 colnames ID, MTH2_v1, MTH2_v2. Sorry I haven't got a clue how to change your code to do that!